# fedora 36 on virtualbox vm root partition size in df is wrong

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I installed Fedora "minimal install" from the Fedora 36 server edition ISO, as a guest, onto Virtualbox 6.1 running on Windows 11 host.

When I created the VM, I gave it 2 gb ram and 32 gb disk (everything default, except for the 32, which was originally 8). During the anaconda installer, I just used the automatic partitioning and made no changes to the partitioning. For software selection, I changed from the default "Server edition" to "minimal install".

Everything went smoothly, but when I logged in the first time, I did `df -h` and to my surprise, the reported total root space was 16 gb, which is only *half* as much as the 32 I had initially gave my VM. See screenshot below.

What gives? I have similar installations of Archlinux guest and Debian guest on the same Virtualbox, and in those installations, `df -h` shows a root partition with about the same as what I gave the VM (which in both of those cases was 8 gb each).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default partitioning for Fedora Server (and this depends on type of media you install from, not the software selection during installation) is [15 GiB logical volume for `/`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-server/installation-an-introduction/#_what_default_partitioning_does) and leaving rest of the space in the volume group free.

If you wish to use all the space for your `/` run

```
sudo lvresize --resizefs -L+100%FREE fedora_fedora/root
```

XFS (default for Fedora Server) can be resized when mounted so you can do that from your running system.

Comment: that link is for "single-board computers like raspberry pi", so I can't really tell whether that's still relevant in my case (Fedora 36 server guest on windows 11 on an ordinary desktop. Anyone know where else this "default partition of 15 GiB" is mentioned? when I installed Fedora originally, I double checked the "automatic partitioning" and it said "31 gb", with no mention of "15 gb" anywhere.

Comment: I updated the link, I didn't realize the previous one was for ARM64 images, but the default is same for both -- the installer will use the entire disk for the LVM volume group and then create a single 15 GiB logical volume for `/` leaving the rest of space in the volume group free.